How to write text on a line in forest package?
I have drawn a stemma codicum using the forest package, but I would need to write some text next to the line that connects a to b. Can anyone help me? Thanks
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  empty nodes/.style={%
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   [$\omega$
     [$\phi$,s sep=1cm
       [$\theta$,l=2cm, tier=1,s sep=0.5cm
         [C, tier=3,l=2cm]
         [D, tier=3]
         [Fl,l=4cm,tier=7]
         [E, tier=3]
         [$\chi$,tier=5
           [O]
           [Ve,l=1.4cm]
         ]
         [F,l=2.4cm]
       ]
       [Q,tier=7]
       [M,tier=5]
     ]
     [$\beta$,s sep=1.5cm
       [$\gamma$,s sep=1cm
         [W, tier=1,name=b]
         [$\sigma$, tier=3,name=a
           [V, tier=4]
           [Z,l=1.6cm,tier=5]
         ]
         [B, tier=2]
       ]
       [$\delta$,l=1.5cm
         [$\varepsilon$, tier=2,s sep=1cm
           [P]
           [U, tier=3]
           [$\eta$,l=1.7cm
             [R, tier=4]
             [T, tier=4]
           ]
         ]
         [S, tier=3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   \draw[->] (a) to (b);
 \end{forest}
\end{document}



Like this? Add text width or align if you need multiple lines.
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  empty nodes/.style={%
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   [$\omega$
     [$\phi$,s sep=1cm
       [$\theta$,l=2cm, tier=1,s sep=0.5cm
         [C, tier=3,l=2cm]
         [D, tier=3]
         [Fl,l=4cm,tier=7]
         [E, tier=3]
         [$\chi$,tier=5
           [O]
           [Ve,l=1.4cm]
         ]
         [F,l=2.4cm]
       ]
       [Q,tier=7]
       [M,tier=5]
     ]
     [$\beta$,s sep=1.5cm
       [$\gamma$,s sep=1cm
         [W, tier=1,name=b]
         [$\sigma$, tier=3,name=a
           [V, tier=4]
           [Z,l=1.6cm,tier=5]
         ]
         [B, tier=2]
       ]
       [$\delta$,l=1.5cm
         [$\varepsilon$, tier=2,s sep=1cm
           [P]
           [U, tier=3]
           [$\eta$,l=1.7cm
             [R, tier=4]
             [T, tier=4]
           ]
         ]
         [S, tier=3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   \draw[->] (a) to node [midway,left] {some text} (b) ;
 \end{forest}
\end{document}


EDIT
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\forestset{%
  empty nodes/.style={%
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   [$\omega$
     [$\phi$,s sep=1cm,name=phi
       [$\theta$,l=2cm, tier=1,s sep=0.5cm
         [C, tier=3,l=2cm]
         [D, tier=3]
         [Fl,l=4cm,tier=7]
         [E, tier=3]
         [$\chi$,tier=5
           [O]
           [Ve,l=1.4cm]
         ]
         [F,l=2.4cm]
       ]
       [Q,tier=7]
       [M,tier=5,name=m]
     ]
     [$\beta$,s sep=1.5cm
       [$\gamma$,s sep=1cm
         [W, tier=1,name=b]
         [$\sigma$, tier=3,name=a
           [V, tier=4]
           [Z,l=1.6cm,tier=5]
         ]
         [B, tier=2]
       ]
       [$\delta$,l=1.5cm
         [$\varepsilon$, tier=2,s sep=1cm
           [P]
           [U, tier=3]
           [$\eta$,l=1.7cm
             [R, tier=4]
             [T, tier=4]
           ]
         ]
         [S, tier=3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   \draw[->] (a) to node [midway,left] {some text} (b) ;
   \draw [->] (b) -- ($(phi)!.5!(m)$);
 \end{forest}
\end{document}


thank you very much for your help! Might I ask you another thing? I would need to draw an arrow from W pointing to the line that connects $\phi$ to M. the line should start from W and end in the middle of the line connecting $\phi$ to M.

@Andrea See edit.
