How to draw lines in forest package?
I would need to draw a line from W pointing to the line that connects $\phi$ to M. the line should start from W and end in the middle of the line connecting $\phi$ to M. Can anyone help me? Thank you
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  empty nodes/.style={%
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   [$\omega$
     [$\phi$,s sep=1cm
       [$\theta$,l=2cm, tier=1,s sep=0.5cm
         [C, tier=3,l=2cm]
         [D, tier=3]
         [Fl,l=4cm,tier=7]
         [E, tier=3]
         [$\chi$,tier=5
           [O]
           [Ve,l=1.4cm]
         ]
         [F,l=2.4cm]
       ]
       [Q,tier=7]
       [M,tier=5]
     ]
     [$\beta$,s sep=1.5cm
       [$\gamma$,s sep=1cm
         [W, tier=1,name=b]
         [$\sigma$, tier=3,name=a
           [V, tier=4]
           [Z,l=1.6cm,tier=5]
         ]
         [B, tier=2]
       ]
       [$\delta$,l=1.5cm
         [$\varepsilon$, tier=2,s sep=1cm
           [P]
           [U, tier=3]
           [$\eta$,l=1.7cm
             [R, tier=4]
             [T, tier=4]
           ]
         ]
         [S, tier=3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   \draw[->] (a) to node [midway,left] {some text} (b) ;
 \end{forest}
\end{document}


You could use the TikZ calc library:
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{%
  empty nodes/.style={%
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,anchor=north}{}}
  }
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   [$\omega$
     [$\phi$, name=phi, s sep=1cm
       [$\theta$,l=2cm, tier=1,s sep=0.5cm
         [C, tier=3,l=2cm]
         [D, tier=3]
         [Fl,l=4cm,tier=7]
         [E, tier=3]
         [$\chi$,tier=5
           [O]
           [Ve,l=1.4cm]
         ]
         [F,l=2.4cm]
       ]
       [Q,tier=7]
       [M,tier=5, name=M]
     ]
     [$\beta$,s sep=1.5cm
       [$\gamma$,s sep=1cm
         [W, tier=1,name=b]
         [$\sigma$, tier=3,name=a
           [V, tier=4]
           [Z,l=1.6cm,tier=5]
         ]
         [B, tier=2]
       ]
       [$\delta$,l=1.5cm
         [$\varepsilon$, tier=2,s sep=1cm
           [P]
           [U, tier=3]
           [$\eta$,l=1.7cm
             [R, tier=4]
             [T, tier=4]
           ]
         ]
         [S, tier=3]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   \draw[->] (a) to node [midway,left] {some text} (b) ;
   \draw[red,->,shorten >=0.15cm] (b) -- ($(phi)!0.5!(M)$);
 \end{forest}
\end{document}



thank you very much!

@Andrea You're welcome!

@Andrea Please leave a link to your followup if you first ask in a comment and then ask a new question. I need not have spent time editing my earlier answer if I'd known samcarter had already answered using exactly the same method I used.

Cross-post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718061/how-to-write-text-on-a-line-in-forest-package#comment1785190_718067

@cfr Sorry to hear about your time, but it's a nice confirmation that you used the same approach. If a TikZpert like you also solved the problem like this, my answer can't be completely wrong :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It wasn't your answer I was complaining about ;). In fact, I upvoted it. I was just annoyed that I'd duplicated your effort unawares. If you look at my answer, you'll see I did precisely the same thing in my followup edit. (Except I used a lowercase m and my arrow isn't red.) It's fine the OP asked a followup when I wasn't around for a while, but a link would have been appreciated so I'd know the edit wasn't needed. And I'm no TikZpert.

I completely understand the frustration. When working on answers in the latex tag on stackoverflow, it is always very disappointing to discover the question has been cross-posted here and is already answered. A simple link by the OP could easily avoid such situations.
